# All notifications disappearing after opening one of them

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have a server that sends me push notifications and let's say that I have 5 notifications on my phone. If I open one of them all other notifications disappears. I want only the one clicked to disappear.

This is how I handle receiving notifications:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Background  )
    {
        // navigating user to a view controller
    }
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

Comment: There is no way to remove a specific notification as of iOS SDK 5.0. When you tap on notification of your app so they don't show in the Notification Center.

Comment: It is because of  application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0,remove that code.Also not sure only the one clicked to disappear.

Comment: @muku by  application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 is only change badge number of application not notification.

Comment: @ParthDabhi if u set this code application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0  then ur badge number and notifications from notification center are all cleared

Comment: @muku notification not clear by that, only app badge you can set. you can change badge number without any notification olso see here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042898/ios-8-change-app-badge-number-without-any-notifications]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent a notification disappear from notification center when another one is opened? iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45174124/how-to-prevent-a-notification-disappear-from-notification-center-when-another-on)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By setting the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` to `0`, you also remove every notification from the notification center.

This has also been discussed here:
[iOS application: how to clear notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682051/ios-application-how-to-clear-notifications)

Furthermore, it is not possible to programmatically remove a single notification, but from iOS8 on, the OS will handle this for you when a user taps a single notification. This has also been discussed here:
[Remove single remote notification from Notification Center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925854/remove-single-remote-notification-from-notification-center)

Comment: you can set badge number ecplicitly without removing any notification.

Comment: @almis you can go for this solution [http://stackoverflow.com/a/28152751/4472625]

Answer (score 2):

If you use **OneSignal SDK** in your app, and you have the problem of disappearing notifications after opening one, you must add key `OneSignal_disable_badge_clearing` to the `Info.plist` file in Xcode, as a Boolean type set to `YES`.

More info here https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/badges

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` to the real number of notifications the user has in the notification center. I made a function for this:

```
func updateIconBadge() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications { notifications in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = notifications.count
        }
    }
}
```

For more info (like where to call to this function) you may want to check my original answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54296486/8157190