# React Native - All notifications clear out from the notification tray on launch of app

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

I am using PushNotificationIOS for my iOS app notifications handling. 
When the app is in background and I get notifications they show up in the tray. But when I open the app(either by tapping on notification or the app icon) all the notifications get cleared from the tray.

Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232822/all-notifications-disappearing-after-opening-one-of-them) that says this happens due to setting the applicationIconBadgeNumber to 0. But I am not doing it anywhere in my app.

Comment: Did you integrate the native code from https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html? Can you show us any code at all?

Comment: Yes @Dan. That's all there in place and the notifications work all fine. Just that it gets cleared on launch of the app. 
Happens on switching the app from background to foreground.

Comment: My application does the same, thats the default behaviour of a notification. If you receive one, then open the app, it gets cleared.

Comment: I believe that should happen only if I tap on the notification. And only the one that I tap on should get cleared.
Found [this](https://snack.expo.io/rk7VdlH6b) expo link to check notifications. Notifications don't get cleared until I click on them.